# Morse Code Conversion

Tags: python, beginner, strings, programming-challenge, morse-code

#### Challenge

Write a program which reads a file containing Morse Code and outputs the conversion.

#### Specifications

1. The first argument is a path to a file.
2. The file contains multiple lines.
3. Each line is a string of Morse code.

   - Each letter is separated by a space.
   - Each word is separated by two spaces.

#### Constraints

1. The input file is correctly formatted.
2. The Morse Code strings are alphanumeric.

**Sample Input**

> ```
> .- ...- ..--- .-- .... .. . -.-. -..-  ....- .....  
> -... .... ...--
> ```

**Sample Output**

> AV2WHIECX 45
>   BH3

[Source](https://www.codeeval.com/open_challenges/116/)

**My Solution:**

```
import sys
import re

morse_alphabet = {
    ''      : ' ',
    '.-'    : 'A',
    '-...'  : 'B',
    '-.-.'  : 'C',
    '-..'   : 'D',
    '.'     : 'E',
    '..-.'  : 'F',
    '--.'   : 'G',
    '....'  : 'H',
    '..'    : 'I',
    '.---'  : 'J',
    '-.-'   : 'K',
    '.-..'  : 'L',
    '--'    : 'M',
    '-.'    : 'N',
    '---'   : 'O',
    '.--.'  : 'P',
    '--.-'  : 'Q',
    '.-.'   : 'R',
    '...'   : 'S',
    '-'     : 'T',
    '..-'   : 'U',
    '...-'  : 'V',
    '.--'   : 'W',
    '-..-'  : 'X',
    '-.--'  : 'Y',
    '--..'  : 'Z',
    '-----' : '0',
    '.----' : '1',
    '..---' : '2',
    '...--' : '3',
    '....-' : '4',
    '.....' : '5',
    '-....' : '6',
    '--...' : '7',
    '---..' : '8',
    '----.' : '9'
}

def decode(morse):
    decoded = ''
    line = re.split('\s', morse)
    for letter in line:
        decoded += morse_alphabet.get(letter)
    return decoded

def main(filename):
    with open(filename) as input_file:
        for line in input_file:
            print(decode(line))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        main(sys.argv[1])
    except:
        sys.exit("No argument provided / file not found.")
```

Applying the insight gained from my [previous question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/135132/converting-morse-code/135136#135136). It seems fairly succinct but I wonder is it pythonic?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My remarks are similar to last time.  `morse_alphabet` should be `MORSE_ALPHABET`.  Repeated string concatenation (`decoded += …`) is bad for performance.  The main task could be accomplished using a one-liner substitution.

```
MORSE_ALPHABET = {
    ' '     : ' ',        # Note: Changed the key from '' to ' '
    '.-'    : 'A',
    '-...'  : 'B',
    '-.-.'  : 'C',
    …
}

def decode(morse):
    return re.sub(' ?( |[.-]*)', lambda m: MORSE_ALPHABET.get(m.group(1)), morse)
```

The main code would be simpler if you used [`fileinput`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html).  Despite the current Pokémon craze, you should not Catch 'Em All, but only catch the exceptions that you intend to handle.

```
def main():
    try:
        for line in fileinput.input():
            print(decode(line), end='')
    except IOError as e:
        sys.exit(e)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: If there are no arguments argv[1] will raise an IndexError

Comment: @FabiánH.jr. I never use `argv`. If there are not arguments, it will read from `sys.stdin`.

Comment: Oh nice, didn't know about that; will def read more about fileinput.

Comment: @Legato Any `'\n'` that may be in the input is simply passed through unchanged by `decode()`. Since the newline was never stripped in the first place, it doesn't need to be added, either.

Comment: Realized the error, thought about it in terms of my original at first. Thank you.

Comment: Nice answer. "_Despite the current Pokémon craze, you should not Catch 'Em All, but only catch the exceptions that you intend to handle_" made my day ^^

Answer (score 5):

No need to do a regex; Python already has [str.split()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)
and you can condense it to a `''.join(generator)`

```
def decode(morse):
    return ''.join(morse_alphabet.get(letter)
                    for letter in morse.split(' '))
```

Comment: Instead of a list comprehension, omit the `[]` and make it a generator expression.

Comment: Done, thanks for the suggestion @200_success

Comment: Is this really valid...? I get an error trying to run it.

Comment: Yes, it is valid python. Could you do me a favour and tell me the output of `python --version`?

Comment: I'm running version 3.4.3

Comment: Add [] around the generator; I tested the code on Python 3.5.2 and it is working great.

Comment: @Legato You may want to handle the case of the newline symbol, as `split(' ')` won't remove it.